# How to apply background image in sending email using django

Tags: django

I hope the title is enough to understand my problem. i just want to add in my email_html background image.

this is my email_html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-image: url('https://myschoolapp.school.com/static/emailbackground.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
<tr>
<td>
<p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<table role="presentation" width="800" height="750" style="background: url('https://myschoolapp.school.com/static/emailbackground.jpg') center / cover no-repeat #000000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" > 
<tr>
<td >
<p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```